# Don't repeat yourself on Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a function in Javascript and I've spent quite a bit of time trying to work out how to make it so I 'Dont repeat myself', really struggled for a few hours with it.

```js
let navOne = document.getElementById('nav__1');
let navTwo = document.getElementById('nav__2');
let navThree = document.getElementById('nav__3');

for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {

  let bgImage = document.getElementsByClassName('nav__content--bg')[i];

  navOne.addEventListener("click", function() {
    bgImage.classList.remove('active');
    document.querySelector('.nav__image--1').classList.add('active');
  });

  navTwo.addEventListener("click", function() {
    bgImage.classList.remove('active');
    document.querySelector('.nav__image--2').classList.add('active');
  });

  navThree.addEventListener("click", function() {
    bgImage.classList.remove('active');
    document.querySelector('.nav__image--3').classList.add('active');
  });

}
```

```html
<!-- nav backgrounds -->
<div class="nav__content--bg nav__image--0"></div>
<div class="nav__content--bg nav__image--1 active"></div>
<div class="nav__content--bg nav__image--2"></div>
<div class="nav__content--bg nav__image--3"></div>

<!-- nav lower panel -->
<div class="nav__content--lower">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="four columns">
      <h3 class="navBtn" id="nav__1">About us</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="four columns">
      <h3 class="navBtn" id="nav__2">Colleague <br> testimonials</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="four columns">
      <h3 class="navBtn" id="nav__3">Join the team</h3>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

The desired behavior i'm wanting is on the click of .navBtn to hide and show the retrospective images.
I.e. nav__1 > hide all > show image--1

I have achieved with the code above, but I know it can be much cleaner and shorter.

I have looked a fair bit of time for a solution, and can't seem to find one. If someone could either point me in the direction or give me some guidance, I'd really appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get a node's list of `.nav__content--bg` elements with `Document.querySelectorAll()`. Get a node's list of `.navBtn` elements with `Document.querySelectorAll()`, and iterate it with `NodeList.forEach()`. Add an event listener to each element (`el`). When click get the respective `.nav__content--bg` using the index of the current button.

**Note**: you've got 4 `.nav__content--bg` divs and only 3 `.navBtn` elements.

```js
const navContentBgs = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__content--bg');

document.querySelectorAll('.navBtn')
  .forEach((el, i) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', evt => {
      navContentBgs.forEach(elm => elm.classList.remove('active'));
      
      navContentBgs[i].classList.add('active');
    });
  });
```

```css
.nav__content--bg:not(.active) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- nav backgrounds -->
<div class="nav__content--bg nav__image--0">0</div>
<div class="nav__content--bg nav__image--1 active">1</div>
<div class="nav__content--bg nav__image--2">2</div>
<div class="nav__content--bg nav__image--3">3</div>

<!-- nav lower panel -->
<div class="nav__content--lower">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="four columns">
      <h3 class="navBtn">About us</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="four columns">
      <h3 class="navBtn">Colleague <br> testimonials</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="four columns">
      <h3 class="navBtn">Join the team</h3>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hey man, this works fantastic, do you know any resources that can show me this further? And yeah the initial image is just a placeholder until one others is activated.

Comment: You're welcome. Start by reading [MDN JS docs] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly less repetitive version of your javascript code:

```js
let navs = document.getElementsByClassName('navBtn');

for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {

  let bgImage = document.getElementsByClassName('nav__content--bg')[i];

  for (let navNumber = 0; navNumber < 3; navNumber++) {

    navs[navNumber].addEventListener("click", function() {
      bgImage.classList.remove('active');
      document.querySelector('.nav__image--' + navNumber + 1).classList.add('active');
    });

  }
}
```

All I've done is put all the navs in one nodelist, and then added a second `for` to loop through them. This means you only need to write the code within this loop once.